# Dot product element wise - one vector dotted with every column in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I am having a bit of a problem figuring out how I could do a dot product for a whole matrix, each column to the same vector. Meaning, this is no problem:

```
p0 = [2; 3; 4]; 
N = [1 ; 2; 3];
dot(p0,N);
```

But If  I have this matrix (I have one with 10095 columns and 3 rows):

```
R = [1 2 3 4 5 6 4 7; 1 4 5 8 7 6 9; 1 5 7 6 9 7 5]
```

How can I create a new matrix with the dot products dot(columnR, N) - meaning I would end up with in my case matrix with 10095 dot products, where each column had been dotted with N.

Comment: That is a matrix multiplication. In MATLAB that is `*`. I recommend that you read an introductory text book on linear algebra, that stuff is very important to understand.

Comment: Of course!!!! haha thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment this is matrix multiplication, although in your case one of the matrices needs to be transposed.

Any of `R.' * N` or `N.' * R` should do the trick.